# What is the proper dress code for a one Michelin star restaurant in Paris?

Tags: paris, clothing, restaurants, dress-codes

We are going to Paris on a short trip and have booked a nice restaurant with one star in Michelin guide. Now we are debating what an acceptable dress code is in such a place. Suit? Not jeans? Dress?

[image: suit]

We are also debating if there actually are restaurants in Sweden - where we live - where you would be turned away if showing up in jeans. I think not but my wife thinks otherwise. This is a sliding value that certainly were different 10 years back. We think that dress codes in France may be more formal than in Sweden. Sweden may well be one of the most relaxed countries in the world with regard to this.

[Photo](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jonomueller/5915912323/) by jonomueller at flick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will differ; although it's likely to be smart casual or smarter, there is variation even at the Michelin star level (some Michelin-starred are more casual, others less so).

Your best option is to call the restaurant and ask. They should be able to discreetly explain it to you :)